# Why looping through all div's childs + removing them starts working only after X uses?

Tags: javascript, frontend

why this code is not removing all nodes after first use, but it does after e.g 2 or 3 times?

```
function remove()
{
    var nodes = document.getElementById("test").childNodes;

    for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++)
    {
      nodes[i].parentNode.removeChild(nodes[i]);
    }
}
```

Use button a few times:

https://jsfiddle.net/ekbadocs/

Comment: Because `childNodes` updates when you add/remove elements. Instead, use `var parent = document.getElementById('test'); while(parent.firstChild) parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild);`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol write it as an answer, so ill be able to accept. Thanks

Comment: Or reverse the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you forgot some node when deleting

## first call

```
var nodes = document.getElementById("test").childNodes;
console.log(nodes)// NodeList(5) [ #text, div.red, #text, div.green, #text ]

// here's what append in for loop
// i | nodes[i]  | nodes
// 0 | #text     | #text, div.red, #text, div.green, #text
// 1 | #text     | div.red, #text, div.green, #text
// 2 | #text     | div.red, div.green, #text
// 3 | undefined | div.red, div.green
// 4 | undefined | div.red, div.green
for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++)
{
    nodes[i].parentNode.removeChild(nodes[i]);
}
```

## second call

```
var nodes = document.getElementById("test").childNodes;
console.log(nodes)// NodeList(5) [ div.red, div.green ]

// here's what append in for loop
// i | nodes[i]  | nodes
// 0 | div.red   | div.red, div.green
// 1 | undefined | div.green
for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++)
{
    nodes[i].parentNode.removeChild(nodes[i]);
}
```

## third call

```
var nodes = document.getElementById("test").childNodes;
console.log(nodes)// NodeList(5) [ div.green ]

// here's what append in for loop
// i | nodes[i]  | nodes
// 0 | div.green | div.green
for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++)
{
    nodes[i].parentNode.removeChild(nodes[i]);
}
```

so it delete only node on odd index in your list each time, because the loop goes one forward while your list change and the values in it "goes one index backward" filling for the position that was emptied

---

use

```
let last; while (last = node.lastChild) node.removeChild(last);
```

to remove every childs of a node, it goes backward to prevent this problem

or keeping your logic, delete only the first value since the element are one index backward at each itération

```
for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++)
{
    nodes[0].parentNode.removeChild(nodes[0]);
}
```

Comment: @Andreas edited but event if I could illustrate it, I'm not sure my phrasing is good enought

Answer (score 0):

because as soon as you remove one node, the whole list is not the same anymore, so the other delete objects doesn't exist anymore.

This is much easier and does the trick:

```
function remove() {
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = '';
}
```

Working example:

```js
  function remove() {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = '';
  }
```

```css
button
{
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
}

.red
{
  background-color: red;
  width: 250px;
}

.green
{
  background-color: green;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div class="red">
    a
  </div>
  <div class="green">
    b
  </div>
</div>

<button onClick="remove();">clickme
</button>
```